# Adding text to email.Body messes with the text formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I'm trying to replace some text in the body of the email, but whenever I do it seems to screw up the formatting of the signature text. For example, if I try `email.Body.Replace("Info", "Information")` then this text:

> **First Last** 
> **Title** 
>  
> Info
>   
> Website: [www.stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)

turns into:

> First Last 
> Title 
>  
> Information 
> Website: HYPERLINK
>   "http://www.stackoverflow.com/"www.stackoverflow.com

This happens even with just a simple addition to the text like `email.Body += "text"`.

Along with this, it also switches the font of the body from Arial 10 to Calabri 12 (this probably has to do with Calabri 12 being the default email text when Arial 10 is the signiture font).

How would I save the format of the current email body so that when I add text to it, I could set it back or what would be the best way to add text to the body to keep the formatting?

Your help would be welcomed.

Comment: some code would be great.  That looks like a RTF hyperlink.  Try adding your text to the RTFBody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MailMessage.Body can be formatted in RTF, which I think it does by default, or in HTML. What the top message you posted actually looks like is something like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255;}
{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sl240\slmult1\lang9\f0\fs22 First Last \par
Title \par
\par
Info \par
Website: {\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "www.stackoverflow.com"}}{\fldrslt{\ul\cf1 www.stackoverflow.com}}}\f0\fs22\par
}
```

I'm assuming that appending "text" to the end of that is causing the RTF message to be parsed improperly, resulting in a loss of formatting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.body.aspx

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer because you mentioned the email.HTMLBody. I ended up using the HTMLBody by creating an HTML `<p></p>` before `</body></html>` at the end of the HMTLBody. I'll post another answer with more detail, but it was thanks to Tim that I got as far as that.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I ended up doing was using the email.HTMLBody. I created a paragraph block similar to what the HTML already had. This is the block: (my HTML isn't very good so... a lot of if is copy/paste with some editing)

```
<p class=MsoNormal>
    <b>
        <span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif"'>Replace Text
        </span>
    </b>
</p>
```

I set this to a string, say htmlPar, then do a replace:

`string htmlReplace = htmlPar.Replace("Replace Text", myNewText");`

This will create a paragraph block that I can add to the HTML with whatever my text is. To actually add it to the end of the HTMLBody I do a string.Replace like so:

```
string temp = email.HTMLBody.Replace("</body></html>", htmlReplace + "</body></html>");
email.HTMLBody = temp;
```

With this I was able to keep the formatting in the rest of the email. Like I said, my HTML isn't great so I'm not sure if this could work to add text in general or how good of a method doing it this way actually is.

Either way, I hope this can help someone else down the road.